# What is "Large Box 8-32 IP Stud"?

Tags: electrical

I bought a plate to cover an unused electrical ceiling box. The package says that the box needs to have a "Large Box 8-32 IP Stud". The plate does not fit on my ceiling box, so I'm assuming I don't have this, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: How about a picture of the plate, label and the box.

Answer (score 1):

8-32 is a common thread pitch for small *machine screws* aka bolts.

8 is the nominal diameter (the hole it's made for).
-32 is the thread pitch in threads per inch.

8-32 is very widely used on junction box cover screws. If I came upon a random junction box and had to climb the ladder with 2 screws in my teeth, I'd pick 8-32 as my best bet.

No relation to 10-32, the slightly larger diameter but same thread-pitch machine screw used for ground screws on junction boxes.

Comment: I would think that the "stud" portion of the description would refer to an 8-32 threaded rod attached to the box that a nut would fit over, however, that doesn't seem to be the case...